# Indirect Speech - Tense Shifting

Tags: tenses, indirect-speech, backshifting

In this quoted example, is it okay to shift verb tenses mid-sentence?

Background: The narration is written in present tense. The narrator is referencing something that was said in the past, but the information in that sentence is presently true.

Version 1:

> She **said** the world **would** never be the same now that we
>   **knew** angels **were** real. **I'm** not so sure.

OR Version 2:

> She **said** the world **will** never be the same now that we
>   **know** angels **are** real. **I'm** not so sure.

OR Version 3

> She **said** the world **would** never be the same now that we
>   **know** angels **are** real. **I'm** not so sure.

Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

She said the world would never be the same once we knew angels are real.

I put in "once" because the way you had it was just too awkward.

"Angels are real" is a statement of fact, like a natural law, and so should be in the present tense.

"I'm not so sure" doesn't work here because it's not clear whether you are doubting that the world would never be the same, or that angels are real.  So you'd just have to rewrite that part completely.